# CSS drop-down menu menu not showing sub-menu on hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

CSS drop-down menu not showing sub-menu on hover, but find out the actual problem. Below are the HTML and CSS. Please see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7bmbxd6/).

It looks `display: block;` has no effect at all.

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0;
}
.inline-menu,
.inline-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.inline-menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.inline-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.inline-menu > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
.inline-menu > li > ul:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span class="logo"></span>

  <ul class="inline-menu left-menu">
    <li><a href="">L-A</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">L-B</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `hover` to the wrong element- use this:

```
.inline-menu > li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}
```

instead of `.inline-menu > li > ul:hover`

```css
body{
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 0;
}

.inline-menu,
.inline-menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.inline-menu > li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.inline-menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.inline-menu > li > ul{
    display: none;
}

.inline-menu > li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span class="logo"></span>

  <ul class="inline-menu left-menu">
    <li><a href="">L-A</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">L-B</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @user1187968 so this solved your issues right? let me know your thoughts... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#menu ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #0C3;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
#menu ul li a {
  color: #CC0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
  background: #C30;
  color: #FFF;
}
#menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#menu ul li:hover> ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">L-A</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">L-B</a> 
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">C</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">D</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </li>
</div>
</div>
```